# curl syntax in google script to obtain access token

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to using API connections to get data into Google Sheets using google script.

**How do I write the CURL request below in Google Script?**

```
curl -u {client_id}:{client_secret} \
 https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/token \
  -X POST -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={your_redirect_uri}'
```

And this one

```
    curl https://api.podbean.com/v1/analytics/podcastReports \
  -G -d 'access_token={access_token}' -d 'podcast_id={podcast_id}' -d 'year=2018'
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question. I apologize for this. So, can I ask you about your question? Your question is `How do I write the CURL request in Google Script to get the access token?`? Or, your question has several questions?

Comment: @Tanaike - no I made the question too complicated. I will edit it. If you could advise how to write the CURL request in Google Script that would help me a lot.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my environment, I could confirm that the requests of each script are the same with the curl command. But when you tested the scripts and an error occurs, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the error message?

Comment: @Tanaike genius. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the following 2 curl commands to Google Apps Script.

  1. Curl command 1.

     ```
      curl -u {client_id}:{client_secret} \
      https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/token \
      -X POST -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={your_redirect_uri}'
     ```
  2. Curl command 2.

     ```
      curl https://api.podbean.com/v1/analytics/podcastReports \
      -G -d 'access_token={access_token}' -d 'podcast_id={podcast_id}' -d 'year=2018'
     ```

#### Sample script for Curl command 1:

```
function sample1() {
  // Please set your values to the following variables.
  const client_id = "your client_id";
  const client_secret = "your client_secret";
  const code = "your code";
  const redirect_uri = "your redirect_uri";

  const params = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri
    },
    headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(`${client_id}:${client_secret}`)},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  const url = "https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/token";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

#### Sample script for Curl command 2:

```
function sample2() {
  // Please set your values to the following variables.
  const access_token = "your access_token";
  const podcast_id = "your podcast_id";
  const year = "2018";

  const baseUrl = "https://api.podbean.com/v1/analytics/podcastReports";
  const url = `${baseUrl}?access_token=${access_token}&podcast_id=${podcast_id}&year=${year}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

#### Note:

- **Before you use above scripts, please confirm your values of `client_id`, `client_secret`, `code`, `redirect_uri`, `access_token`, `podcast_id`, `year` in the scripts again.**
- About "Sample script for Curl command 2", when the special characters are included in the values of `access_token` and `podcast_id`, please use `encodeURIComponent()` to the values like `` const url = `${baseUrl}?access_token=${encodeURIComponent(access_token)}&podcast_id=${encodeURIComponent(podcast_id)}&year=${year}`; ``.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)